# How to preselect values in CategoryFilterBuilder?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to preselect values in CategoryFilterBuilder

According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts

**CategoryFilterBuilder** - *"Starts building a category filter control, as described in the Google Chart Tools documentation."*

In documentation we see that https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#categoryfilter
has selectedValues state.

Unfortunately I can't trigger it via apps script.

Example: *Google Chart Tools with preselected values* https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization&hl=de#categoryfilter_control

Please help me pre select month "Aug" in this example https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/category-filter-builder

Comment: Can't do it - best to add a request to [issues list](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).